# Error in saving bitmap image in internal storage

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, bitmapimage

[image]

I want to save bitmap image in internal storage.but i got syntax error. i goggled that error but cannot get appropriate solution.

Comment: pls read the FAQ of the site to know how to ask a question with enough details. You have a method inside `onClick`??

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to declare a method inside another method. Move `saveToInternalSorage()` below `onCreate()`. Also post the code here directly. Don't post it as a screenshot.

Comment: ok.Xaver Kapeller. thanks for commenting . the problem was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error shown bcz you makes function on onClickListener. Try below code:-

```
        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                saveToInternalStorage();
            }
        });
```

saveToInternalStorage function:-

```
        public void saveToInternalStorage()
        {

        }
```